# Notify on Windows via Python but not archive the notification

Tags: python, notifications

To notify that an error was encountered when running the code, I do it like this:

```
from plyer import notification

def notifyerror(notify_error_alert_text,time_appear):
    notification.notify(
        title = 'Visual Studio Code\nError:',
        message = notify_error_alert_text[:250],
        app_icon = None,
        timeout = time_appear,
    )
```

```
notifyerror('bla bla bla bla bla',1)
```

But as my need is only momentary and I don't need to see them in the future, I come across such a problem...

These notifications that appear on the screen are being archived and accumulating:

[image]

Is there any way to be able to notify via Python but without these notifications accumulating and only visually warning me at the moment and disappearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way: to notify without archive the notification, a viable option for Windows 10 and Windows 11 is to use `win10toast` as `ToastNotifier`:

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

def notify_windows(notify_error_alert_text,time_appear):
    toaster = ToastNotifier()
    toaster.show_toast("Visual Studio Code",
                notify_error_alert_text[:250],
                icon_path=None,
                duration=time_appear,
                threaded=True)
```

```
notify_windows('bla bla bla bla bla',1)
```

In this example form, the notification appears and the code continues running without pauses, with the notification appearing for 1 second on the screen and disappearing without accumulating in the notification bar or hidden icons.